# Как вывести данные из базы данных контроллер?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Возможно вопрос написан некорректно, пожалуйста внесите правку, если можно.

Есть два контроллера и две модели:

**Контроллер**: People**s**

**Контроллер**: Article**s**

**Модель**: People / В базе модели стоит поле: **firstname**

**Модель**: Article / В базе модели стоит поле: **title**

views/articles/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>   <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>   <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>   </div>
    <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :firstname%><br>
  <%= f.text_field :firstname%>
</div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>   </div> <% end %>
```

Как в представлении выше сделать так что бы форма отправляла в базу данных не только `title` но и `firstname`?

Ругается так:

```
undefined method `firstname' for #<Article id: nil, title: nil, created_at: nil,
updated_at: nil>
```

Он как бы мне я понимаю, что говорит: метод `firstname`, который я использую, неизвестен.

Comment: Приведенный код не имеет к сообщению об ошибке никакого отношения.

Comment: А как тогда написать? Проблема ведь есть, пока не могу решить. Я не представляю как заставить представление form пренадлезащую контроллеру Article сабмитить данные модели people. Пробовал так: app/views/products/_form.html.erb
<%= select_tag(:people_id, options_for_select(@peoples)) %>  Почти работает но всё равно думаю не то

Comment: А вы не думайте, тестируйте. Оно либо работает, либо неправильно. Что касается ошибки: начните с перевода её текста и установления места, в котором она возникла.

Comment: По обновлённому коду -- руби не врёт, у вас действительно странный код: форма ведь для создания статьи, а у статьи нет поля `firstname`. Человек у вас там нигде не фигурирует. UPD: и кстати, `People` это уже множественное число, единственное `Person`. Я б скорее ожидал увидеть модель `Person` и `PeopleController` **(звучит-то так, контроллер людей!)**, Rails скорее всего тоже в некотором замешательстве, и чудо, если не давится этим.

Answer (score 0):

В коде ошибка, у вас форма для модели `Article`,  а вы пытаетесь передать ещё параметр из другой модели, о чем вам и говорит текст ошибки. Для того чтобы из одного view сохранять данные в несколько моделей можно сделать форму абстрактной(то есть не указывать для какой она модели, а указать например `form for :mydata`) и создать отдельный контроллер в котором массив данных, полученный с запросом(params[:mydata]), разбивается по полям и сохраняется в нужные модели. Но, по моему мнению, чтобы не усложнять структуру лучше создать отдельные view для каждой модели. Для примера, и в обще чтобы упростить себе коддинг, посмотрите `gem 'casein'`, он генерирует все необходимые view для моделей.